# What are the challenges of designing high Q digital filters?

Tags: filter, digital-filter

I am not familiar with digital filters and digital signal processing.
I do know that implementing an analog filter with a high quality factor is not practical, because (please correct me if I'm wrong) we are limited by the Q of active components in the circuit, and tuning a high Q filter is difficult. (Any other significant reasons?) We don't have these problems in the digital domain, do we? Is there a reason we would want to avoid high Q digital filters?

Comment: You can make practical analogue filters with Q-factors many times the Q-factors of the basic components. Seems that your question may be based on this misconception?

Comment: @Andyaka My questions is mainly about problems with digital filters, but it would be nice to refine my knowledge of analog filters too.

Answer (score 2):

High Q filters, have poles very close to imaginary axis (unit circle for digital filters). When implemented on a digital platform, the truncation errors introduced in the coefficients can push the poles of the filter to the right had side plane (outside unit circle for digital filters). The resulting filter is unstable. *Passive*, analogue filters won't have this problem.

Another problem occurs if the gain is very high; Arithmetic overflow can occur in the internal states / variables.

Even if it doesn't overflow, adding large signals with small signals can cause the addition to be ineffective if both the numbers vary by large orders of magnitude. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186589/why-does-adding-a-small-float-to-a-large-float-just-drop-the-small-one)

With floating point arithmetic (and enough number of bits) this may be very unlikely to happen and can anyway be tested before deployment.